# .Net code coverage using OpenCover

Tags: iis, opencover

I am using Open Cover to get .net code-coverage, command used is

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe" -targetargs:"-debug -s 3" -targetdir:"XXX" -register:administrator -output:"D:\TestCaseNewOpencover.xml"
```

I initially stopped IIS : `net stop w3svc /y`

Executed Open cover and started application to get coverage.

When i performed these steps in Windows 7 and IIS 7.5 it worked perfectly but when ui replicate this in Windows 8 and IIS 8.5 application is not coming up... In browser its showing `"Unable to connect"`.

Can anyone help on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance ..

---

Hi Shaun Thanks for reply.

Now i am trying to execute opencover with IIS now i am facing a issue like opencover is not generating complete report ... i have project with multiple packages.. only for one package its getting coverage others are not covered even though tht classes are hit while testing.
Command used : 
OpenCover.Console.exe -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" -targetargs:"/path:XXX /port:1234" -register:administrator -output:"D:\IISExpressOC123"
D:\IISExpressOC123 - generated reposrt has oly first package files parsed.

I could identify this by generating report using ReportGenerator.

Can i know how to solve this issue and get complete coverage ??

Comment: I know not an answer but I've always recommended using IISEXPRESS if they insist on using OpenCover for integration testing like this. Alternatively I use self-hosting far easier to control again than IIS.

Comment: The output XML normally carries information against each assembly it sees and a reason as to why it didn't instrument it.